# What is the inverse of $\tanh$?

Tags: geometry

How to find out the value of $Z$?

$A = \tanh(Z)$

Here I know $A$.

How to find the value of $Z$?

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922852/prove-formula-operatornamearctanh-x-frac12-ln-left-frac1x1-x-rig no quadratics.

Comment: Many software engineers are not super familiar with the math concepts or have forgotten some concepts, and now we see machine learning everywhere! I would like moderators not to just downvoting questions like this. Genuinely many software developers don't have a background in machine learning math and applying ML as a tool. So would appreciate a bit helpful approach!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** If $\tanh(z)=a$, then

$$\frac{e^z -e^{-z}}{e^z + e^{-z}} =a$$

If we substitute $y=e^z$, then this equation becomes

$$\frac{y-\frac{1}{y}}{y+\frac{1}{y}}=a$$

Can you solve this equation for $y$? (Spoiler alert: it can be simplified to a quadratic.)