# Question about Poincare disc model D

Tags: geometry

Suppose σ is a circle centered at (h,k) such that σ∩D is a P-line.

a. Show that the equation of σ is x^2+y^2-2xh-2yk+1=0.
b. Find the P-length d(A,B), where A=(-1/2,0) and B=(0,-1/2).

And then we are asked the following question, [image]

For a, I let the point (a,b) be the point lies on σ and intersect the disc orthogonally,
hence I have (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = (a-h)^2 +(b-k)^2
and since a^2 +b^2 =1, I get x^2+y^2-2xh-2yk=1-2ah-2bh
which is a bit off from the desired answer.

For b, I tried to find where A and B intersect with the circle by plugging in the value of A and B into the equation from a. Then used the formula d(AB)=|log(AB,PQ)| to find the p-length. But I get a very strange number.

And for c , I don't know where to start with.

Comment: Please format your math with Mathjax.

Answer (score 1):

Question a) : the equation of circle $\sigma$ is

$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2 \ \iff \ x^2+y^2-2hx-2ky=r^2-(h^2+k^2)\tag{1}$$

Besides, using the orthogonality property, Pythagoras gives us:

$$1+r^2=h^2+k^2 \ \iff \ r^2-(h^2+k^2)=-1\tag{2}$$

Plugging (2) in (1), we obtain the desired result.

Question b) : formula $$d(A,B)=|\operatorname{ln}(A,B;P,Q)|$$ is too difficult to apply here (I have begun the computations, obtained the equation $x^2+y^2+\tfrac52(x+y)+1=0$ of the circle containing $A$ and $B$, but afterwards, it becomes too complicated).
Fortunately, there is another formula with complex numbers $a=-1/2$ and $b=-i/2$ associated with $A$ and $B$:

$$d(A,B)=2 \operatorname{arctanh} \left|\frac{b-a}{1-\overline{a}b}\right|=2 \operatorname{arctanh}|\tfrac{10-6i}{17}|\approx 1.681$$

Please note that there is "logarithm" function hidden in the previous formula; indeed:

$$\operatorname{arctanh} x = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

See a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2922852).

Comment: No comment ?...